# How to assign each row of a text file to a new vector?

Tags: c++, text-files, fstream

I am C++ noob, I have a text file with 4 rows and 3 columns, where each row corresponds to a sensor signal. How do I load each row to a separate `vector<float>`?

```
(0.165334,0) (0.166524,-0.0136064) (-0.144899,0.0207161)
(0.205171,0) (0.205084,-0.0139042) (-0.205263,0.0262445)
(0.216684,0) (0.215388,-0.0131107) (-0.193696,0.0251303)
(0.220137,0) (0.218849,-0.0135667) (-0.194153,0.025175)
```

This is what I have so far, but this code  loads data as string. I want to load my final data as `vector<vector<float>>`?

```
vector<vector<string> > input;    
ifstream fileFFT(Filename.c_str());
string line;
while(getline(fileFFT, line)){
    if(line.empty()){
        continue;
    }

    stringstream row(line);
    vector<string> values((istream_iterator<string>(row)),(istream_iterator<string>()));       //end

    input.push_back(values);

}
```

Comment: Do you *need* a vector of vector of string?  Or will a vector of strings be sufficient?

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ read file CSV".  There are already a plethora of similar questions.

Comment: You may want to search the internet for "c++ read file matrix coordinates".  Always a good idea to search the internet before posting.

Comment: I want to load them as vector<vector<floats>>

Comment: @spandy, if you know the elements are always two in length it might be better to use `std::pair`, `std::array` or even your own class or struct, rather than a nested vector.

Comment: No, you don't want a vector<vector<float>>.  You want a `std::vector<std::vector<Point> >` or `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<float,float>>>`.

Comment: Use a custom struct, or a tuple, pair, or array. Do not use a vector. A vector is for dynamic content, or where the size is unknown at compile time. Use a more fixed data structure, your code will thank you later. All the suggestions above highlight how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

```
class Point
{
public:
  double x;
  double y;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Point& p);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Point& p)
{
  char c;
  input >> c; // Read open parenthesis
  input >> p.x;
  input >> c; // Read comma
  input >> p.y;
  input >> c; // Read closing parenthesis
  return input;
};

//...
std::string row_text;
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> matrix;
while (std::getline(my_file, row_text))
{
  std::vector<Point> row;
  std::istringstream(row_text);
  Point p;
  while (row_text >> p)
  {
    row.push_back(p);
  }
  matrix.push_back(row);
}
```

I've created a `Point` class to represent the pair of floating point numbers.

I also overloaded `operator>>` to make reading a `Point` easier.

The loop reads one *record* or text line, then creates a vector of `Point` from the text line.
The record or row is then appended to the matrix.

Comment: how do I print the elements of `matrix` vector?

Comment: You could use `matrix[row][column]`.

Comment: I get following  ` error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'Point')`

Comment: In the `Point` class overload `operator <<` to print to an `std::ostream`.  There a gazillion examples on the internet on how to overload `operator<<`.

Comment: Thanks for you help,

Answer (score 2):

You have half the answer already - use `std::getline()` to read each line, and then use `std::(i)stringstream` to process each line.

Now, what you are missing is the other half - parsing each line.  And since you already know how to use `std::istream_iterator`, I would do something like this:

```
typedef std::pair<float, float> SensorValue;
typedef std::vector<SensorValue> SensorValues;

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, SensorValue &out)
{
    float f1, f2;
    char ch1, ch2, ch3;

    if (in >> ch1 >> f1 >> ch2 >> f2 >> ch3)
    {
        if ((ch1 == '(') && (ch2 == ',') && (ch3 == ')'))
            out = std::make_pair(f1, f2);
        else
            in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }

    return in;
}

...

std::vector<SensorValues> input;

std::ifstream fileFFT(Filename.c_str());
std::string line;

while (std::getline(fileFFT, line))
{
    if (line.empty())
        continue;

    std::istringstream row(line);

    SensorValues values;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<SensorValue>(row), std::istream_iterator<SensorValue>(), std::back_inserter(values));

    input.push_back(values);
}
```